# Azure 'list_resources' Method Lists Deleted Managed Disk

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group, azure-managed-disk

Even after a managed disk is deleted from the `resource group` in `Azure`, if you call the `list_resources` to list the remaining resources in that resource group, the managed disk still shows up even if you have deletion confirmation notification visible in the `Activity Logs` on Azure Portal.

[image]

As you can see, the logs clearly say that the disk has been deleted, yet I can still see it being listed in the `list_resources` method.

It is visible for up to 2 minutes after delete has been called on it.

Does anyone know why the `list_resources` method still ends up listing it?
Because if you try calling `get` on the managed disk, it will return you an exception saying that the disk was not found, yet it still shows up in the list.

**Note**

I am using Azure SDK for Ruby Gem v0.9.0.

Method Link in SDK => [List Resources Method](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/8f00dbbc1706c439ba11d0420b05f62b112ed469/management/azure_mgmt_resources/lib/generated/azure_mgmt_resources/resource_groups.rb#L39)

Comment: you sure you calling a method, not getting variable value?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I don't understand what you mean